# different color for different levels of rows in jsTree

Tags: css, jstree

how can get **different row color** for different 'level' of rows in jsTree

let's say that in my sample http://jsfiddle.net/radek/sTmrv/2/

- **basics & all** will have the same color
- **login, Basics of Edu, login, Add Academic year** .... will have the same but different color
- and finally the **3rd level** will have the same color.
- so far I managed to change color of all rows ....

Comment: I dont know if I get it right or this will work with Javascript. Have you tried the nth-child(N) pseudo class.

Comment: I don't know what `nth-child(N) pseudo class` is ....

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you? See http://jsfiddle.net/sTmrv/4/

You may have to play with it a bit (untested in IE).

```
li.jstree-open > ul {
    background: red;
    display: block;
}
li.jstree-open > ul li.jstree-open > ul {
    background: #CCC;
    position: relative;
    left: -18px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: it looooooooks gooooood. Two more questions. How would change the color of the first level. Any chance you can explain what you did? ;-)

Comment: .jstree-default.jstree-focused {
    background: green;
} should do it.

Comment: I inspected the CSS using Firebug (http://getfirebug.com). If you haven't used it before, you can install it as a Firefox add-on, then right-click on any part of the screen to see the CSS styles for any element.

Comment: I was more after this http://jsfiddle.net/radek/Yf8PG/ thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a loop with a generated row id, and base the colors on the multiple of the row Id.. let me try typing up something quickly.

Comment: I was thinking if I can somehow use current code without introducing new classes

Comment: on the other hand I don't know where to add the class :-)